# Cordova G.maps plugin build failed with not have OS required enviroment

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ant, maps

I have followed the tutorial to install the plugin google maps into a project **Cordova** but I have a problem . When I run the build I get an error at 84% of the process, error can be seen [image: here]
.

I have installed `ANT`, `SDK`, configured path and all is the latest version.
But failed with code same in the image.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I found that the plugin is no longer supported and serving API old , the 17 seems to work .
Now use the API of google , many simpler